# Change Data Capture - is it possible to get updates that happened prior to the start of the subscription?

Tags: change-data-capture

We want to build a service that monitors Salesforce that gets changes to Opportunities as they occur. If we could assume 100% uptime, this strategy would be perfect. But if we have to bring the service down to perform maintenance, we will miss changes and that could cause our local representation of the Opportunities to get out of sync.

Is it possible with **Change Data Capture** to get changes that occurred prior to the subscription? Let's say we have a sequence of events like this...

- Our service starts - Subscribe to OpportunityChangeEvent at 09:00
- Event: Amount changed to 50000
- Event: Stage changed to Negotiate
- Service goes down for maintenance - Unsubscribe at 10:00
- Event: Type changed to Renewal at 10:02
- Service goes back up - Subscribe to OpportunityChangeEvent at 10:05

Can we find out about that last event that took place between 10:00 and 10:05?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are a lot of ways you could design this integration, but perhaps using a combination of the [Oppportunity History](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityhistory.htm) and [Opportunity Field Tracking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunityfieldhistory.htm) Objects would be helpful. You could process each of these records and you could handle it all asyncronously if needed.